# Updating oneToMany entity sets parent to null

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, one-to-many, many-to-one

I have a list of `Role` entities on a `User` entity linked with a `@OneToMany` relationship. When I change the list on the `User` entity, i.e change the roles, hibernate removes the old roles and adds the new ones as desired. However the foreign key field is set to null on the `Role` entity.

Can you explian why the foregign key field is null, and how would I change it so it gets picked up on an update?

**User.java**

```
@SerializedName("userrole")
@Expose
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "user", fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
private List<Role>   userRoles = new ArrayList<Role>();
```

**Role.java**

```
@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "user")
private User user;
```

**Table Before**

```
+----+------+------------------------+
| id | role | user                   |
+----+------+------------------------+
|  1 |    0 | digby.tyson@gmail.com  |
|  2 |    1 | digby.tyson@gmail.com  |
|  3 |    2 | digby.tyson@gmail.com  |
|  4 |    3 | digby.tyson@gmail.com  |
|  5 |    4 | digby.tyson@gmail.com  |
|  6 |    5 | digby.tyson@gmail.com  |
|  7 |    6 | digby.tyson@gmail.com  |
|  8 |    7 | digby.tyson@gmail.com  |
|  9 |    5 | ronny.polley@gmail.com |
| 10 |    6 | ronny.polley@gmail.com |
| 11 |    7 | reed.robert@gmail.com  |
+----+------+------------------------+
```

**Table After**

```
+----+------+------------------------+
| id | role | user                   |
+----+------+------------------------+
|  9 |    5 | ronny.polley@gmail.com |
| 10 |    6 | ronny.polley@gmail.com |
| 11 |    7 | reed.robert@gmail.com  |
| 12 |    0 | NULL                   |
| 13 |    1 | NULL                   |
| 14 |    2 | NULL                   |
| 15 |    5 | NULL                   |
| 16 |    6 | NULL                   |
| 17 |    7 | NULL                   |
+----+------+------------------------+
```

**Hibernate actions**

```
Hibernate: select userroles0_.user as user3_2_0_, userroles0_.id as id1_1_0_, userroles0_.id as id1_1_1_, userroles0_.role as role2_1_1_, userroles0_.user as user3_1_1_ from role userroles0_ where userroles0_.user=?
Hibernate: insert into role (role, user) values (?, ?)
Hibernate: insert into role (role, user) values (?, ?)
Hibernate: insert into role (role, user) values (?, ?)
Hibernate: insert into role (role, user) values (?, ?)
Hibernate: insert into role (role, user) values (?, ?)
Hibernate: insert into role (role, user) values (?, ?)
Hibernate: update user set first_name=?, last_name=?, middle_name=?, organisation_id=? where email=?
Hibernate: delete from role where id=?
Hibernate: delete from role where id=?
Hibernate: delete from role where id=?
Hibernate: delete from role where id=?
Hibernate: delete from role where id=?
Hibernate: delete from role where id=?
Hibernate: delete from role where id=?
Hibernate: delete from role where id=?
```

**Update**

The method that calls the database as requested in comments

```
@Override
@Transactional
public User update(User user) throws UserNotFoundException {
    String updatedUserEmail = user.getEmail();

    if (userRepository.findByEmail(updatedUserEmail) == null)
        throw new UserNotFoundException();

    return userRepository.save(user);

}

@Transactional
public interface UserRepository extends CrudRepository<User, Long> {
```

Thanks for any help in advance.

Comment: Looking at the table data it is a manyTomany relationship. But in your entities you have mapped is as OneToMany. You need to update ur entities to manyTomany as well. Also post your code that is performing the update.

Comment: I think roles should be entities that have independent lifecycle from users. And you have them mapped as `cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true` ie. when a user is deleted, it deletes also the roles (not just the relationship between the user and the roles). Is that really your intention?

Comment: @AdamMichalik Yes, I want to be able to delete a user and all roles related to that user be removed from the roles table.

Comment: @SJC - Can you please explain then your example: user `digby.tyson` has role `7` and user `reed.robert` has role `7`, too. Is it the same role `7` in both cases? If so, then as @Madhusudana Reddy Sunnapu said - it's a many-to-many relationship, because many users can have the same role and one user can have many roles. Now, when you delete user `digby.tyson` do you really want that role `7` is deleted and thus removed from user `reed.robert` too? Or do you just want the *assignment* of role `7` to `digby.tyson` be deleted?

Comment: Just the roles from `digby.tyson` should be deleted when the `user` is deleted. All other roles are left in the table. As @MadhusudanaReddySunnapu suggested I added the `@ManyToMany` on the user and I am getting an error on launch `Illegal attempt to map a non collection as a @OneToMany, @ManyToMany or @CollectionOfElements` Thanks btw

Comment: What is the name of that "Table before" "Table after" that you put on your question ? User ... Role ... or a third table named UserRole ?

Comment: @Pras Apologies, that table is the roles table.

Comment: Then that "role" column in there is just some number related to nothing right ? ... I mean, it is not a foreign key on another table ?

Comment: @Pras that role column is the value of an enum which represents the actual role, so for example 0 could be the role of admin

Comment: OK, so your mapping is correct ....

Answer (score 0):

Mapping is correct, now what you want to achieve is when removing a Role from User, you want that role to be deleted (orphanRemoval = true).

This is a Bidirectional Association, so what you have to do is make the changes in both sides to keep your object model consistent :

```
// remove role from user one-to-many
user.getUserRoles().remove(roleToBeDeleted);
// remove the many-to-one association
roleToBeDeleted.setUser(null);
```

Comment: Thanks for the replies, however the table before and after is the currently what happens. My problem is I don't want the `NULL` values in the after table, I want them removed completely. Would the above do this, or am I right in saying your answer is to make the after table?

Comment: Try the above first ... and let me know ;) ... it should work just fine !

Answer (score 0):

I did this with EntityManager and using Hibernate and it seems to be working OK. Are you taking the old role out of the `List<Role> userRoles`?

User:

```
@Entity
public class User {
    @Id private String email;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "user", fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
    private List<Role> userRoles = new ArrayList<Role>();
```

Role:

```
@Entity
public class Role {
    @Id @GeneratedValue private Long id;

    @ManyToOne
    private User user;
```

running it as:

```
User u = em.find(User.class, "test@test.com");
Role e = new Role();
e.setUser(u);
u.getUserRoles().remove(0);
u.getUserRoles().add(e);
em.merge(u);
```

Gives me:

```
Hibernate: insert into Role (user_email, id) values (?, ?)
Hibernate: delete from Role where id=?
Hibernate: select * from role
```

And in the roles table is only one row:

```
[2, test@test.com]
```