# Link Parent and Child entities Hibernate JA

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, many-to-many, one-to-many

I have struggled to get a good way to relate a `Role` entity to my `User` entity in Java Hibernate. I have a `User` entity which has a List of `Role` entities. I want to relate them so if a `User` is deleted all the `Role` entities which have that `User` are also deleted with a cascade or the like.

I started off with a `@OneToMany` (`User`) & `ManyToOne` (`Role`) relationship between the two entities, but when I delete the User it just set the column which contained the `user` in the `role` table to `NULL`. It was then suggested the relationship was `@ManyToMany` however this caused `Illegal attempt to map a non collection as a @OneToMany, @ManyToMany or @CollectionOfElements` which I have yet to successfully resolve. Hence I ask what is the best way to achieve the desired relationship between the `User` and `Role` before i go too far down the rabbit hole.

Please note: In this example the `Role` is more of a permission, so users can have the same permission but they are linked to the username. In the table below you can see `digby.tyson` has the same `role` as `reed.robert` no. 7, but if `digby` was deleted then the `role` on `reed` should remain

**User.java**

```
@SerializedName("userrole")
@Expose
// @OneToMany(mappedBy = "user", fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
private List<Role>   userRoles = new ArrayList<Role>();
```

**Role.java**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "role")
public class Role {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long     id;

    @NotNull
    private RoleEnum role;

    // @ManyToMany / @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "user")
    private User user;

    [Getters & Setters]
```

**Sample Table**

```
+----+------+------------------------+
| id | role | user                   |
+----+------+------------------------+
|  1 |    0 | digby.tyson@gmail.com  |
|  2 |    1 | digby.tyson@gmail.com  |
|  3 |    2 | digby.tyson@gmail.com  |
|  4 |    3 | digby.tyson@gmail.com  |
|  5 |    4 | digby.tyson@gmail.com  |
|  6 |    5 | digby.tyson@gmail.com  |
|  7 |    6 | digby.tyson@gmail.com  |
|  8 |    7 | digby.tyson@gmail.com  |
|  9 |    5 | ronny.polley@gmail.com |
| 10 |    6 | ronny.polley@gmail.com |
| 11 |    7 | reed.robert@gmail.com  |
+----+------+------------------------+
```

Thanks for any feedback, I have tried to solve this issue for over a day, so it would be much appreciated.

Comment: Delete a `Role` with a corresponding `User` is a very strange thing. `Role` is a reference as usual.

Comment: @v.ladynev `Role` is acting as a permission in this scenario, and the table just stores all `roles` associated with a `User` so when the `User` no longer `exists them entries are no longer needed.

Comment: It should be named as the `Permission`, isn't it?

Comment: @v.ladynev I agree, it should be, and eventually it would be, however my main task it to get what is already written working, then I can refactor

Comment: do you realize you need a join table with many-to-many or a unidirectional one-to-many?

Comment: @Ramanlfc I did not, I am new to Hibernate and its annotations, so was asking for guidance in this endeavor. WouldI do this with a `@JoinTable` annotation and of so which side do you recommend? Also in your opinion is many-to-many or one-to-many the best way to go?

Comment: Based on your scenario, what you're likely to want is many-to-many association between `Role` and `User`. Many-to-Many relationship would need a join table which only has user id and role id. With a many-to-many relationship your `Role` class would need to have a `Collection<User> users` and `User` class need to have `Collection<Role> roles`

Comment: read this and decide what relationship you want , otherwise it's difficult to answer your question if you aren't sure about what relationship you need http://www.objectdb.com/api/java/jpa/annotations/relationship

Comment: @Bunti Thanks for that, I did what you said, and it does update the database now. However I have noticed that the `role` table which has an incremental id and `role` (in the form of a number), does not get deleted when the `user_role` join table does.

Comment: I cannot confidently say anything without seeing the updated source code you have. Normally you have to delete manually any fields, in your case `role` which are still there. This makes sense because this same role can be associated to some other user(because it is many-to-many). I'm off to bed now. You can find a similar answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1082095/how-to-remove-entity-with-manytomany-relationship-in-jpa-and-corresponding-join) on how to delete this type of relationship

Comment: @Ramanlfc I think now after looking into the relationship I need a Unidirectional OneToMany. This is because there is no way to update a Role. You can only create one and assign it to the 'User' Roles list. 
The roles of a 'User' will be altered by adding or removing them in the User's Roles list. Can you give me a heads up on how to implement this. I have been trying to solve this issue for the last few days.

Comment: try this :
`@JoinTable(name="user_roles", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name="user_id"),inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name="role_id"))
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "user", fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
    private List<Role> userRoles = new ArrayList<Role>();`

Comment: @Ramanlfc I tried what you suggested, but I am getting an error `Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory` when I try and run the app.

**User.java**
`@JoinTable(name="user_roles", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name="email"),inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name="role_id")) @OneToMany(mappedBy = "user", fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true) private List<Role> userRoles = new ArrayList<Role>();`

**Role.java**
`@ManyToOne private User user;`

Comment: It seems you are asking the same question again.Did the last answer not satisfy? [Updating oneToMany entity sets parent to null](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36050088/updating-onetomany-entity-sets-parent-to-null/36073666#36073666)